# comparar una columna con otra con un if

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Soy nuevo trabajando con Mysql, actualmente estoy intentando hacer el siguiente query, no se si sea correcto hacerlo de esta manera:

```
select A.*, max(A.DoneDate) as last ,if(A.DoneDate = last,'yes','no') as isLastOne from helios.FSA_Audits A;
```

Cuando lo ejecuto medice unknown column *last*.

**Como puedo hacer para que pueda comparar con el valor de esa columna?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los alias que defines en el `select` sólo están disponibles luego de su ejecución. En este caso ienes que usar `select ... , IF(A.DoneDate = max(DoneDAte, 'yes', 'no') as isLastOne ...`